# minus indent on top in single page navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, singlepage

I'm a beginner in Javascript/Jquery, so I really hope you are gracious with my code and my question.

Please visit my Example and click on a section link.
You can see (maybe use an Inspector), that the section on the top is a little bit indented. I guess it depends on the changing header.

When you click a second time, the position is correct - this means - if the style from the header is already switched - there is no problem anymore.

[Example on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/elkeschiffer/pen/BzWjLv)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

// smooth anchor scrolling

$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

```
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
  }, 500);
```

});

// sticky Navigation
  var stickyNavTop = $('.sticky-navi').offset().top;

```
var stickyNav = function(){
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
    $('.sticky-navi').addClass('sticky');
} else {
    $('.sticky-navi').removeClass('sticky');
}
};

stickyNav();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyNav();
});
```

});

Does someone has a solution for me … please … :)?

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to race condition. When you get offset to scroll to nav is not sticky yet, but while scrolling down conditions change when nav is sticked to page top thus offset needed to scroll to link becomes invalid. You need to compensate for that.

```
var nav = $('.sticky-navi');
var oft = nav.hasClass('sticky') ? 0 : nav.height();
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - oft
}, 500);
```

What this does is subtracts height of nav when it is not sticky. This is because we know nav will be sticked to page top during scrolling. When it is already sticky we do not need to do anything.